# Connection Refused on Recv(), while send seems to work fine

Tags: c++, sockets, send, recv

I am trying to create a connection to a server/port that I'm provided - Upon making the connection, I am able to send it ping packets( at least I think I am able to, since send() seems to return the correct number of bytes), but when I try to recv() right after, the call fails saying

```
"Error on Receiving .. Connection Refused"
```

Any ideas on why the send would not be giving an error, but recv would ? This following is the part of code causing my failure -it's running on it's own thread. The TCP connection was made on another thread, and that socket descriptor was passed to this one(it's called m_sockfd below).

```
void ConnectionManager::operator()()
{

  int rc = 0, numBytes=0 ; 
  char reply[256] ; 

  // Send a ping
  char PingPacket[23] ; 
  PreparePingPacket(PingPacket) ; 
  numBytes = send(m_sockfd,PingPacket,23,0); 
  if(numBytes == -1)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error on Sending Ping .. \n") ;   
    return ; 
  }
  if(numBytes < 23)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Didn't send the whole Ping Request .. %d \n", numBytes) ;  
  }

  numBytes = recv(m_sockfd, reply, 256, 0) ; 

  if(numBytes == -1)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error on Receiving .. %s \n", strerror(errno)) ;   
    return ; 
  }

  ParsePacket(reply, rc) ; 
}
```

I can paste my code which does the actual connection, but I'd figure if it had the error, then the send would have never gone through to begin with ?

Thanks for reading  - any help appreciated !

Comment: Get a Winsock error code using WSAGetLastError() and then use [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741580(v=vs.85).aspx) to see what it means.

Comment: I ran my code on my university's servers, and it works flawlessly - It seems I'm only hitting this issue at home. I had used port forwarding to direct all the traffic coming to a specific port - and verified that by making sure the incoming connection is able to come through, but not sure why recv() is issuing a 61/Connection Refused.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out - it was something extremely stupid from my side. The issue was with my getaddrinfo() statement. I was somehow passing in the "struct addrinfo" hints after memsetting it to all 0's. This caused the endpoint to be invalid somehow. After placing the memset before changing the values in the structure, this problem went away. Still not sure how the sends went through, but that was the problem.